# using grep --recursive, how to exclude specific line with the 'unwanted' and 'wanted' word in it?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm currently building my dotfiles and I want to list all `TODO: ...` comments in my project's directory, I created a bash alias to do this:

```
 alias mytodo='grep --recursive "TODO: "'
```

It works well, however, it also returns the alias definition. this is the sample output.

```
 devs@dotfiles$ mytodo

 bash/profile.d/aliases/: alias mytodo='grep --recursive "TODO: "'
 bin/git_branch_status/: # TODO: Add checking of remote branch status.
 tools/setup/: # TODO: Add search for existing symlinks.
```

how can I specifically exclude that line with the alias definition?

Comment: Consider also `—exclude=glob` as a way to exclude files named alias

Comment: @JeffSchaller i don't want to exclude the file as I may write todo comments in it, I just wanna exclude that specific line with the alias definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to prevent a regexp from matching itself is to enclose a single character in a character class:

```
alias mytodo='grep --recursive "TOD[O]: "'
```

Alternatively (hat-tip to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470226/using-grep-recursive-how-to-exclude-specific-line-with-the-unwanted-and-wa/470228#comment857637_470228)), you could save the alias with extra quote-marks in the pattern:

```
alias mytodo='grep --recursive "TO''DO: "'
```

Then the line still won't be found, but the alias contains the original pattern.  This is helpful when you want to use eg. a fixed-string match (`grep -F`).

Comment: it works now! Thanks. I will accept this as the answer..

Comment: Or `alias mytodo='grep --recursive "TO''DO: "'` which still creates a `grep --recursive "TODO: "` alias.

Comment: Most used case: `ps <some-option> | grep "[p]rocess"` to avoid showing the `grep` process every time

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pipe it into `grep -v 'alias'` to get all lines which don't contain `alias`.

Comment: it works with `grep -v 'alias' | grep -r 'TODO: '` but for some reason it messed up the colors of the grep output.. any idea why?

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan Do you already have a `grep` alias?  That's typically where the `color` option is set.

Comment: I already aliased the grep with `--color=auto` so i think its because of the piping.. I tried to reverse the order of the command and it works with colored output but it freezes.